# Strapi reDeployment breaks my images! - Digital Ocean

Tags: strapi

So i have a Strapi app that I deployed to digital ocean app platform. This is what I want to be the cms of the site. In various stages of building, I have had to go back and tweak the data and content types. My issue is everytime I do this and redeploy via Github, it breaks the articles I already had that were working.

I will need to add sections as I go and now I am afraid I will keep breaking strapi because I will need to rebuild admin everytime. Locally I have sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PostgreSQL or MySQL in production: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/faq#why-are-my-applications-database-and-uploads-resetting-on-paas-type-services

Comment: I do use posgres in production on the digitalocean side. I only use sqlite in development but not sure why images break when I re deploy